# Concatenation in C# with SQL Query for Access Database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have an Access Db with C# and I am doing a concatenation in sql query aftere where clause but I am getting the following error

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression"

My code is below

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from TEMP1 WHERE EMAIL=" + GlobalData.Email;
```

Please tell me what is causing the error and what the correct syntax is for concatenation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd better use SqlParameter (more secure):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Temp1 WHERE Email LIKE @email")
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("email", GlobalData.Email));
```

To answer to the original question:

Using direct concatenation, without string delimiter, your query become:

```
SELECT * FROM Temp1 WHERE Email LIKE email@email.com
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM Temp1 WHERE Email LIKE 'email@email.com'
```

Comment: Can you delete the first one? The second is much more secure.

Answer (score 6):

I think your your problem is missing quotes.  Try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from TEMP1 WHERE EMAIL='" + GlobalData.Email + "'";
```

But that method can lead to SQL injection if you don't validate the email.  Although there is nothing wrong with the above code, if data is validated, I do prefer to use SQL Parameters:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "SELECT * FROM Temp1 WHERE Email = @Email" )
cmd.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter( "Email" , GlobalData.Email ) );
```

Comment: Yes, the strings in the query have to be placed in quotes.

Comment: If the data comes from user input (which is quite likely), the query is wide open for SQL injection.

Comment: @Guffa One regular expression validating a valid email solved that problem. I would assume that asker validates response before saving to DB, for a very structured string such as email injection is not possible after validation.

Comment: @AndrewJackman: You can't just assume that the validation is there and is safe. It's good that you added a note about it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Parameterised queries](http://www.functionx.com/aspnet_csharp/articles/parameterized.htm) instead. It's usually the norm when working with SQL queries, for security reasons as well as readability.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any apostrophes around the string literal, so your query will end up like:

```
Select * from TEMP1 WHERE EMAIL=someone@somesite.com
```

This will of course cause a syntax error. You need the apostrophes around the string:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from TEMP1 WHERE EMAIL='" + Replace(GlobalData.Email, "'", "''") + "'";
```

However, encoding strings correctly is not trivial. (The above method works for Access and Microsoft SQL Server, but other databases needs other methods.) You should rather use parametrised queries:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from TEMP1 WHERE EMAIL=@email";
```

Then you add a parameter to the command object, for example:

```
cmp.Parameters.Add("@email", DbType.VarChar, 300).Value = GlobalData.Email;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from TEMP1 WHERE EMAIL='" + GlobalData.Email + "'";
```

Comment: This is open to SQL injection. You should at least mention that.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure about the error, but you should try it like that

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM TEMP1 WHERE EMAIL='{0}'", GlobalData.Email);
```

That way you don't need to mess with ugly concatination that btw, takes alot of memory usage.

Comment: If the data comes from user input (which is quite likely), the query is wide open for SQL injection.

Comment: The memory usage used to be true (in .Net 2.0 and earlier), but now, due to compiler optimization, that ugly mess is the most efficient concatenation method (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/303158/String-Concatenation-vs-Memory-Allocation-in-Cshar)

Comment: Actually Francois B. gave you a better example than me using SqlParameters is much better.

Comment: Validation is much helpful in many usages but if you use both SqlParam and validation it will be much safer.